# How to identify EXISTING purchases for non renewing subscriptions without UDID on IOS

Tags: ios, subscription, in-app-purchase, udid, subscriptions

there have been many questions about UDID and identifying users of applications, our app uses UDID to identify a user’s phone, this is how we tied their non renewing subscription purchase to a device

Apple has now banned the use of the UDID on the appstore and because our app used UDID, we find ourselves in a situation where we will be unable to identify existing customers – has anyone else found themselves in the same situation?

Any ideas as to how we will be able to ID our customers purchased subscriptions? It’s a shame that the restore transaction method doesn’t work for non renewing subscriptions.

I suppose we are going to have to get the customer to enter in their Receipt number and compare that to the receipt data we have (I hope they are the same thing!) but any thoughts from the community would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the device's MAC address, so long as you get permission from the user.